# Avoid a specific tech when searching for jobs

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I would like to search for jobs that don't require a specific tech. I tried with minus in front like I do on google:

```
-ruby, -ruby-on-rails
```

and I thought it was working but on the third page I saw ruby jobs.

Is there a way to do that search?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There are two ways for you to do that. You can enter `-[ruby-on-rails]` (using brackets means "this tech tag" instead of "this anywhere on the job") the search box or choose the tags you dislike on our filter pane:

You can also try your query without the comma; it'll get treated as part of the text - it uses the text `ruby,` rather than `ruby`. The analyzer we have configured in Elasticsearch doesn't strip off punctuation for tags (it probably should) and everything starts to go downhill from there!

[image: Using the filter]

Comment: This should be more clear so that people know this.  You guys should look into faceted type searching and guide the user more in terms of how to search more easily.